# Inject Angular into Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, coffeescript

There're a lot of articles on this topic, but in my mind the easiest way to start with are railscast angular and this one http://asanderson.org/posts/2013/06/03/bootstrapping-angular-rails-part-1.html. Each of this articles(videos) share almost the same code. I tried to implement both ways, but neither of them works. This is my way:
*`application.js`*

```
//= require angular
//= require_tree .
//= require underscore
```

*user.js.coffee*

```
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./controllers
```

*assets/javascript/controllers/mainIndexCtrl.js.coffee*

```
@IndexCtrl = ($scope) ->
    $.scope.title = "WWAAAAAAA"

    $scope.Data = {}
    $scope.Data.doClick = ->
        responsePromise = $http.get('/user/photos_show')
        responsePromise.success (data) ->
            $.scope.Data.Response = data
```

*application.html.erb*

```
<html ng-app>
```

*show.html.erb*

```
<%= notice %>
<h3>Hello there <%= @user.name %></h3>
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <p> Here are your albums </p>
    {{title}}
    <% @albums.each do |album|  %>
        <div>
            <%= link_to album.last, album_photos_path( album_id: album.first, album_name: album.last ) %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The libraries I added to vendor/assets/javascript and to gemfile as 2 variant.In the result "title" doesn't show the right way and shows {{title}}. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Any errors in firebug console in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this line has an error (extra dot):

`$.scope.title = "WWAAAAAAA"`

It should be:

`$scope.title = "WWAAAAAAA"`

The other thing is that you are doing some strange hybrid of a 'classic' RoR application and AngularJS application.

In 'classic' RoR application, you are generating dynamic html content using erb, or some other templating engine.

With AngularJS you are serving static html pages, and the 'dynamization' takes place on client side (in clients browser).

I would suggest splitting your application in two parts, the backend based on Ruby on Rails, which acts as an API, and the frontend, a single-page-application based on AngularJS and using tools typical for frontend application, such as Yeoman (http://yeoman.io/)

Comment: Well, that didn't fix the issue(it was a "bad" mine error), but the thing about splitting is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if your html require `application.js`
2. Angularjs file must be exist and you can find in `application.js`
3. View on broswer like Chrome and open console to see if there is any `javascript` error

Usually when you require angularjs correctly and embed `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in html, set `{{1 + 1}}`, then you will see `2` in that page. Still show `{{}}` means angularjs not required success or angularjs scope error

Comment: 1)`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', controller_name %>`, yes it's included.
2) Yes it's defined in app.js and the lib is in vendor.
3) I debugged my page with firebug and get this kind of error.`[ng:areq] Argument 'IndexCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`.Well it's expected I think, cause my app doesnt recognize angular.

Comment: Looks like your coffee code has sth wrong, but I do not use coffee. In js I often define a Ctrl like `var IndexCtrl = ['$scope', function($scope){ $scope.title = 'WWAAAAAAA' }]` and this works.

Comment: sth, wrong?I didn't understand that.About js I tried your way, it still doesn't work the right way.
`var IndexCtrl = [ '$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.title = "WWAAAAAAA";

 $scope.Data = {};
 $scope.Data.doClick = function() {
  responsePromise = $http.get('/user/photos_show');
  responsePromise.success = function(data) {
   $.scope.Data.Response = data;
  };
 };
}];`